# Error in Samsung Devices, report of Google play console "androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: "

Tags: java, android-studio, runtime-error, report, google-play-console

After AAB uploaded on Google Play Console, report showing 1 Crash & ANRs error related to app stability but the error is only Samsung devices (Test device is "Samsung Galaxy S20 5G"). I have try too much i have not get any coding error regarding this. Whats should I do to resolve the bug?

**Report**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
Process: com.shayari.meenaappstudio, PID: 5926
View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=78, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@ca643f3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
at androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException$Builder.build(NoMatchingViewException.java:5)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:20)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8154)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```